# pdf-files: results of "pdfid"

Tags: pdf

Didier Stevens has produced a programme which is called **"pdfid"** (https://blog.didierstevens.com/2009/03/31/pdfid/  and  https://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/pdf-tools/#pdfid).

He says:

> "I’ve developed a new tool to triage PDF documents, PDFiD. It helps
>   you differentiate between PDF documents that could be malicious and
>   those that are most likely not."

And that´s what I want to use it for.

> "PDFiD will scan a PDF document for a given list of strings and count
>   the occurrences (total and obfuscated) of each word:"

```
obj

endobj

stream

endstream

xref

trailer

startxref

/Page

/Encrypt

/ObjStm

/JS

/JavaScript

/AA

/OpenAction

/AcroForm

/JBIG2Decode

/RichMedia

/Launch

/XFA
```

As far as I know the values of "obj" and "endobj" should match which means that there´s no object opened that wasn´t closed (perhaps causing buffer-overflow
or something else).

And ideally

*/JS   /JavaScript   /AA   /OpenAction   /AcroForm*

should have zero value.

Yet I´ve seen quite a lot of pdf-documents with "obj" and "endobj" not matching but the other values seem to be o.k.

Example: Using_FreeDOS.pdf from http://www.freedos.org/ebook/download/using-freedos-24.pdf .

The pdfid-results:

```
 PDF Header: %PDF-1.4

 obj                  520

 endobj               519

 stream               193

 endstream            193

 xref                   1

 trailer                1

 startxref              1

 /Page                100

 /Encrypt               0

 /ObjStm                0

 /JS                    0

 /JavaScript            0

 /AA                    0

 /OpenAction            1

 /AcroForm              0

 /JBIG2Decode           0

 /RichMedia             0

 /Launch                0

 /EmbeddedFile          0

 /XFA                   0

 /URI                   8

 /Colors > 2^24         0
```

Yet this one has also  "/OpenAction  1". I´m not quite sure how relevant that one is.

Nevertheless:

how important is the fact that "obj" and "endobj" match when the rest of the list of strings and count are o.k?

As already said: there are quite a few pdf-documents out there with "obj" and "endobj" not matching.

Answer (score 0):

pdfid is apparently doing a lousy job at counting the obj/endobj pairs -- in your particular example, the odd "obj" is part of a FlateDecode stream:

```
$ cat pdf.pl
use Compress::Zlib qw(inflateInit Z_STREAM_END);
use strict;
my ($o);
while(<>){
        $o -= s/\bendobj\b//g;
        $o += s/\b\d+\s+\d+\s+obj\b//g;
        if(/\bstream\s*$/){
                local $/ = "endstream"; my $s = <>; $s =~ s/\s*endstream$//;
                if($s =~ /(\w*obj)/){
                        my ($d, $err) = inflateInit->inflate($s);
                        if(length($s) == 0 && $err == Z_STREAM_END){
                                warn "innocuous '$1' in well formed stream\n";
                        }else{
                                warn "WARNING: inflateInit: $err\n";
                        }
                }
        }
        if(/(\w*obj)\b/){ warn "WARNING: possible stray $1\n" }
}
warn "WARNING: unbalanced obj/endobj: $o\n" if $o;
$ perl pdf.pl using-freedos-24.pdf
innocuous 'obj' in well formed stream
```

Note: that little is to illustrate the problem at hand; don't use it to check if a pdf is secure ;-)

The pdf format is quite nasty & complex; you really need a full-blown parser to make sense of its structure. And a program that's able to do it (in order to correctly identify malicious pdfs) is becoming an attack vector itself -- there is no reason to believe that an ad-hoc parser is more secure than libpoppler or libmupdf.

Comment: Hi mosvy. Tnx a lot for your assessment. Obviously you understand the whole matter way better than I do. Nevertheless I´ve now used **pdfinfo** from **libpoppler** to evaluate the example-file: `Creator:        Writer
Producer:       LibreOffice 6.0
CreationDate:   Sun Aug 19 15:57:02 2018
Tagged:         no
UserProperties: no
Suspects:       no
Form:           none
JavaScript:     no
Pages:          100
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      611.972 x 791.972 pts (letter)
Page rot:       0
File size:      2405845 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.4
` So I looks fine.

Comment: Hi mosvy, thanks for the perl-script of yours. I tried it out and it gave me the same result. Yet you said I shouldn´t use it to check if a pdf is secure. But are there any objections against using it in addition to libpoppler/pdinfo?